# Extract varying length middle characters

Tags: sql-server

I have the below column and I want to extract character after the first ':' and before the second ':', please help me with this. I am working with SQL Server Express for this. thank you in advance.

```
BN:wagtz2dp01:DPS
BN:wagtzdp02:DPS
BN:wagb2b2dp01:DPS
BN:wagtzdp20:DPS
BN:wagtzdp04-LOYALTY:DPS
BN:wagb2b01:DPS
```

I want the below output:

```
wagtz2dp01
wagtzdp02
wagb2b2dp01
wagtzdp20
wagtzdp04-LOYALTY
wagb2b01
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? This is a great place to start: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a table with column [Text] you can try following.

```
select 
    SUBSTR([Text], CHARINDEX(':', [Text]), CHARINDEX(':', [Text],CHARINDEX(':', [Text])+1))) 
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`

```
SELECT Substring(string, Charindex(':', string) + 1, Charindex(':', string, Charindex(':', string) + 1) - Charindex(':', string) - 1) as Middle_chars
FROM   (VALUES ('BN:wagtz2dp01:DPS' ),
               ('BN:wagtzdp02:DPS' ),
               ('BN:wagb2b2dp01:DPS' ),
               ('BN:wagtzdp20:DPS' ),
               ('BN:wagtzdp04-LOYALTY:DPS' ),
               ('BN:wagb2b01:DPS' ))tc(string)
```

**Result :**

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║   Middle_chars    ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║ wagtz2dp01        ║
║ wagtzdp02         ║
║ wagb2b2dp01       ║
║ wagtzdp20         ║
║ wagtzdp04-LOYALTY ║
║ wagb2b01          ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```